How to click on a chrome extension using Selenium python
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


# Path to Chrome executable and Chrome DevTools port
chrome_path = 'C:\\Users\\tejve\Downloads\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe'
devtools_port = 9222  
# Same port you used to start Chrome #"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222

extension_path = 'C:\\Users\\tejve\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions\\ofaokhiedipichpaobibbnahnkdoiiah\\1.2.0_0'
# Set up Chrome options
options = Options()

# Add the extension by specifying its path
options.add_argument("--load-extension=" + extension_path)

# Set up debugger address
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:{}".format(devtools_port))

# Create a new Chrome session
service = Service(chrome_path)
# Create a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

# Navigate to a webpage
driver.get("https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/marketstats/duration-1d,exchange-nse,pageno-1,pid-0,sort-intraday,sortby-percentchange,sortorder-desc.cms")

# Wait for the page to load completely (adjust the sleep time as needed)
time.sleep(5)  # Wait for 5 seconds, adjust as needed

# CLEAR FILTERS
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='clearAll']").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pageContent"]/div[6]/div[1]/div[4]/button[3]').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[normalize-space()='100 rows']").click()

print("Before performing action")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('l').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

print("After performing action")

Output of the above code-
Before performing action
After performing action
i want the selenium script to press the shrotcut key Control+L but it is not working and almost skipping the actionchain code also not showing any error. Whereas when manually pressing Control+L runs the extension. Please help how to do this.
